# Gmail REST API Example Clarification using PHP

Tags: php, rest, gmail-api

I'm trying to work through the [PHP example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample) provided for the Gmail REST API.

I'm not clear what information I'm supposed to change to my personal information to make the example work. I'm self taught and new to PHP so any info would be appreciated. I've put some comments (MF:) inline with changes I've made but still not working:

```
<?php
//require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //MF: changed to:
require_once('GoogleAPI/src/Google/autoload.php'); 
//MF: The downloaded API from GitHub  doesn't have a "vendor" folder.

//MF: should this be the project name as it appears up in my Google Developers Console? Does it matter?
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Gmail API Quickstart'); 

//MF: I assume I download and put the path to my JSON Download file from the Google Developer console. 
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/gmail-api-quickstart.json'); 

//MF: I'm confused how this differs from the line above. The JSON Download has the client secret in it as well. Is this different?
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json'); 

define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY)
));
```

//MF: I think I leave the rest alone.

```
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
$results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);

if (count($results->getLabels()) == 0) {
  print "No labels found.\n";
} else {
  print "Labels:\n";
  foreach ($results->getLabels() as $label) {
    printf("- %s\n", $label->getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error with Gmail API? please explain clearly what's your issue?

Comment: Your changes seem fine, what's the exact error that occurs when you run your script?

Comment: I was able to see the labels after changing the auth method (was trying to run it as a web app when it was set as an application). Thanks for your help.